# query_posts taking a while to load

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created a simple WordPress website, however, it is taking a while to load. I am filtering out all posts, and only showing those with a tag of `front`:

```
<?php 
query_posts( 'tag=front' );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    ?>
```

I understand this might be a bad practice. If so, why, and is there a simple alternative?

Comment: Do you have a large number of posts?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    $args = array(
        'tag' => 'front',
    );

    $front_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    global $more;
    if ( $front_query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $front_query->have_posts() ) : $front_query->the_post();
            $more = 0;
    ?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                ....
                ....
                ...
    <?php   
        endwhile;

    else :
        get_search_form();
    endif;
?>
```